# How can I call functions on PHP using eval()?

Tags: php, function, eval

How can I call functions on PHP using eval()? is it possible?
I wanna do something like this

```
<?php

$function1 = 'echo';
$function2 = 'implode';
$arr = array('arg1', 'arg2');

eval("$function1 ($function2(', ', $arr));");

?>
```

Or call  other functions with multiple params?
Is eval() what I'm looking for? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try to run this code? It should evaluate correctly. But don't use `eval()`, there are other solutions such as `call_user_func_array()` like Niet mentioned.

Comment: echo isn't a function anyway, it's a language construct

Comment: [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call-user-func) is specifically designed for calling functions by name. Or just `$function1($argument);`.

Comment: But `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: @MarkBaker: Hes talking about `eval`, not `echo`!

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in X:\home\test.com\www\test1.php(6) : eval()'d code on line 1
ive got this error when running this script
and call_user_func needs function to be described in the same script

Comment: The only problem should be that your array becomes `Array` when interpolated into the string; the "functions" should work just fine.

Comment: @Polygnome - `$function1 = 'echo';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to eval anything:

```
$function1 = 'print';
$function2 = 'implode';
$arr = array('arg1', 'arg2');

$function1($function2(', ', $arr));
```

In fact, you can even use variable, variables:

```
$foo = 'print';
$bar = 'foo';

$$bar('hello');
```

Comment: that gives "Fatal error: Call to undefined function echo()"

Comment: Call to undefined function `print()` but works with `print_r()`
Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so print and echo are also language constructs - but the principle is the same. Any function can be called like this.

Comment: All I want is to run `PHP` code distantly.. For example now how many free disc space I got on my server using `curl` and `$_POST`  but i don't want to do it only with one hard code function :) All I tried before was with `echo()`, that because I've got error message, but with other functions it's works fine.. Thanks for advise and sorry for my English :)